# como ejecutar un batch script en un pipeline de jenkins

Tags: batch, jenkins, pipeline

He empezado hace recientemente poco a usar Jenkins. He montado un job que descargar del SCM (Perforce) cuando hay cambios, compila el proyecto (c++) y lo sube a Steam ejecutando un .bat file con un simple script, en freestyle funciona perfectamente, pero ahora me gustaria pasarlo a pipeline, pero no consigo ejecutar el archivo batch, no da ningun error pero se queda eternamente cargando, como esperando alguna respuesta por parte del script quizas?. Esta es mi pipeline:

```
...
Stage('batch script'){
            steps{
                bat 'start C:/Users/User/.jenkins/workspace/Project/Steam Build Scripts/scripts/build_dev.bat'
            }
        }
...
```

Y este el simple script para subir a steam (cogido de la documentacion oficial):

```
"C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Project\Steam Build Scripts\builder\steamcmd.exe" +login "someUser" "somePassword" +run_app_build "C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Project\Steam Build Scripts\scripts\app-build-813780-dev.vdf" +quit
```

Y asi es como lo ejecuto y funciona en el freestyle job:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

ok en caso de que alguien tenga el mismo problema, debido a que el path contiene espacios, tiene que ser llamado asi:

```
                    bat ('call "C:/Users/User/.jenkins/workspace/Project/Steam Build Scripts/scripts/build_dev.bat"');
```